# jquery plugin colorbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did everything like in the documentation. Despite that, It opens image url directly. (documentation: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/guide/)
My code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css">
  <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a class='gallery' href='http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2012/045/b/d/random_cat_hug_x3_by_amyrose27-d4pqktd.jpg'>Photo_1</a>
<a class='gallery' href='img/gallery/2.jpg'>Photo_2</a>
<a class='gallery' href='img/gallery/3.jpg'>Photo_3</a>
</body>

<script>
  $('.gallery').colorbox();
</script>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try to include jquery.js before jquery.colorbox.js in your `<head>`